# What is this sequence called? [0,0,1,0,2,0,2,2,1...]

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence $s_n$ follows these rules
$s_0=0$
$s_{n-k}=s_{n-1},k>0$
If k does not exist, set k to $0$
$s_n=k$
With these rules, you get the sequence $[0,0,1,0,2,0,2,2,1,6,0,5,0,2,6,5,...]$

Comment: Have you tried https://oeis.org/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sequence is [OEIS A181391](https://oeis.org/A181391), aka Van Eck's Sequence.